# projection of a vector onto a plane in $\Bbb R^5$

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

Hy guys, i have some question about this problem.
I have three points $P(1,0,2,0,1)\; Q(0,1,0,1,0)\;R(2,0,1,0,2)$

The parametric representation of the plane $\pi$ which contains that point is

$\{P+s(Q-P)+t(R-P)\;|s,t \in \Bbb R^5 \}$

i.e

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
1-s+t =x_1 \\ 
s=x_2 \\
2-2s-t=x_3\\
s=x_4\\
1-s+t=x_5
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

so my cartesian representation is:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x_1-x_5=0\\
x_2-x_4=0
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$
that is right??
Let's continue:

the problem asks me to find  an orthogonal base of the direction $\pi_0$ of the plane $\pi$.

Isn't the direction the vectors $s(Q-P)+t(R-P)$?

$
s(Q-P)+t(R-P)=\, 
s\left(\begin{matrix} 
   -1\\
    1\\
   -2\\
    1\\
   -1\\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
+
t\left(\begin{matrix} 
    1\\
    0\\
   -1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
$

So, for $s=1$ and $t=1$

$\left(\begin{matrix} 
   -1\\
    1\\
   -2\\
    1\\
   -1\\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
\cdot
\left(\begin{matrix} 
    1\\
    0\\
   -1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{matrix}
\right)
=0$

These two vectors form my orthogonal basis?

The last question: find the orthogonal projection of the vector $v=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ onto the $\pi_0$

Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cartesion representation is not correct. What you got was a $3$-dimensional space, not a plane. You can add to ou pair of equations the equation $x_1+3x_2+3x_3=3$, for instance.

Yes, your two vectors (I will call them $v_1$ and $v_2$) form an orthogonal basis. The projection of $v$ onto $\pi_0$ will be equal to$$\frac{\langle v,v_1\rangle}{\|v_1\|^2}v_1+\frac{\langle v,v_2\rangle}{\|v_2\|^2}v_2.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
+s \left(
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
+t
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right) \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
2 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
+s 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
-2 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
+ t
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} 
\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 -s + t\\
s \\
2-2s-t \\
s \\
1-s+t
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
so we agree.

We need to extract three linear independent equations to describe the two-dimensional plane.

We have $s = x_2$ and $2 x_1 - x_3 = 3t$ so we get
$$
x_3 = 2 - 2s - t = 2 - 2 x_2 - 2/3 x_1 + 1/3 x_3 \iff \\
2/3 x_1 + 2 x_2 + 2/3 x_3 = 2 \iff \\
2 x_1 + 6 x_2 + 2 x_3 = 6
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 - x_5 &= 0 \\
x_2 - x_4 &= 0 \\
2 x_1 + 6 x_2 + 2 x_3 &= 6
\end{align}
$$